# Exploding pandas dataframe on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I am trying to explode a dataframe based on multiple dataframes (infact on a condition where there is a comma in the data anywhere in that column), but end up getting errors when I try on multiple columns.
I have tried split(), explode() etc.

Input
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: What are data type of the columns? Are they strings or lists?

Comment: I am converting them to strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pad_list(lst, max_len):
    return lst + [lst[-1]] * (max_len - len(lst))

new_df = df.apply(lambda row: row.apply(lambda item: pad_list(item.split(','), max(row.str.contains(',') + 1))), axis=1).explode(df.columns.tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    Cat1   Cat2    Cat3    Cat4    Cat5
0    Cat  table     Pen  Toyota  Sydney
0    Cat  chair     Pen   Honda   Perth
1  Horse  Stand  Pencil  Holden    Bali
1  Horse  Stand  eraser  Holden    Bali
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution richardec,  I am getting a "NameError: name 'r' is not defined".. do I need to import any module for that to work with strings?\

Comment: I think there was a typo error in the solution. fixed it and is working      df.apply(lambda row: row.apply(lambda item: pad_list(item.split(','), max(row.str.contains(',') + 1))), axis=1).explode(df.columns.tolist())

Comment: @Shahrukh Yes, I'm sorry. `r` should've been `row`